# Android: Image button as a hyperlink, phone call, map directions?

Tags: android, image, button, hyperlink

I have a simple app that I'm putting together for my company. I have 4 buttons that I've created but can't seem to get them to link correctly. One button should open our mobile site, another button to call us, another button to map to us, and the final button linked to our "News" site. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you accomplished so far?  Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 10):

On your buttons, you should set OnClickListener, and to do some required actions you could see the example below:

1. To Open a Map with Certain Location

   ```
   mapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + your-location-geo-address));
           startActivity(i);
       }
   });
   ```
2. To call certain number

   ```
   callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telephone-number));
           startActivity(i);
       }
   });
   ```
3. To open a website

   ```
   linkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(website-address));
           startActivity(i);
       }
   });
   ```

Change "location-address", "telephone-number", and "website-address" with your own String value.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I put my onclicklistener code? Also, how should the code for my button look in my main.xml file? I'm ridiculously new to this, so I apologize for not knowing what the heck I'm talking about!

Comment: using buttons are pretty basic, have you checked Android SDK's code samples? There are a lot of samples using buttons there. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Answer (score 3):

anmustangs answer is very good, but one thing I would like to add for the button you are making for a link to your site, where anmustangs wrote (website-address)  instead of just typing in a site, it needs to put formatted correctly. For example, you can use "http://www.google.com"   and yes you do need to use the quotation marks I put in there. I know I am years late to this thread but who knows who my post may help.