# How to make button as hyperlink in android

Tags: android

How can I create a button whose text look like a hyperlink text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Image button as a hyperlink, phone call, map directions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826543/android-image-button-as-a-hyperlink-phone-call-map-directions)

Comment: You mean just visually look as hyperlink or look and behave as  hyperlink?

Comment: I just want to make text look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Create a String (named hyperlink) in string.xml and give its value like link and then set property android:setText="@string/hyperlink" to Button.

Comment: I don't think this will do it. This will set the text to the button.

Comment: This is just funny thing this is crap instead excepted WTF

Comment: This seems to be a totally wrong answer. I think you can shape a button as a drawable, to be similar to a link and code a listener to call a url as an intent. If you intend just to change the "look" of the button, it is ok. But if you need that button to also behave as link you must code a onTouchListener or similar.

Answer (score 4):

Easy, you just have to create an TextView and enable the property autoLink="all", and you don't need to pass any HTML, only the url inside a text or just the url.

Example:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please click www.google.com.br and search for anything!"
        android:autoLink="all"/>
```

Comment: This only works if you have text that is parsable as a URL.  If you want to have a link button say "Go to our homepage" this won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I did this way in my Project

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply but this is for opening a Url in browser.And I just want to make text look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score 3):

in your string.xml add:

```
<string name="Test"><a href="http://www.bla.com">Test</a></string>
```

in your TextView add the attribute:

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

Comment: This will give to the TextView just the appearance of a link. When you touch this TextView nothing will happen, because you have to code a listener to call the url as an intent.